weired X11 error
steps to reproduce
1.) install a fresh 24.04 ubuntu
2.) change /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to
a.) enable autologin
b.) disable Wayland
so you have entries like these:
WaylandEnable=false
AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = user1

3.) install thonny - as an example app (apt-get install thonny)
4.) reboot system
5.) start firefox or any other app in full screen mode
6.) start thonny
7.) maximize thonny window
8.) click into the shell tab at the bottom of thonny
for unclear reasons you are switched to firefox
the problem does not occur on wayland.
the problem also does not occur if autologin is turned of

Hello. This isn't the proper place to file a bug report, see below.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Do you have a question you're asking us to solve? as I don't see any. This isn't a bug tracking or reporting site  (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for details on that)
